# How to write jQuery function to show and hide some parts of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got the following HTML code.

```
    <input type="button" id="B1" onclick="return false;" value="Show" />
    <input type="button" id="B2" onclick="return false;" value="Show" />
    <input type="button" id="B3" onclick="return false;" value="Show" />
    <input type="button" id="B4" onclick="return false;" value="Show" />

   <p id="P1">This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
   <p id="P2">This is another small paragraph.</p>
   <p id="P3">This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
   <p id="P4">This is another small paragraph.</p>
```

I would like a jQUERY function to do the folowing.
If I click B1 button it should show P1 text and also the B1 button text should change to Hide and next time when I click B1 button it should hide P1 text and change B1 button text to show. Same for B2 P1, B3 P3, B4 P4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : Use **[jQuery Start With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** and bind click event for all button having id starts with 'B' and show /  Hide respective paragraph.

```
 $(function(){
  //hide all paragraph
  $('p[id^=P]').hide();
  $('input[id^=B]').click(function(){
     var index = $(this).attr('id').replace('B','');
     var lable = $(this).val()=="Show"?"Hide":"Show";
     $(this).val(lable);
     if(lable=="Show")
      $('#P'+index).hide();
     else
      $('#P'+index).show();
  });
});
```

**[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxchmytn/3/)**

Comment: do i need to change any thing on <input type="button" id="B1" onclick="return false;" value="Show" /> i mean how to call that function

Comment: You just need to include jquery library and put above code inside `<script></script>` in header part of html.

Comment: See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide), in code section jquery.min.js included and document.ready is inside script tag. Follow the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) function and the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector to know if the div is open or not:

```
<input type="button" id="B1" onclick="$('#P1').slideToggle();" value="Show" />
```

After, I let you to write the function ;)

Comment: This is working but how do i change the button text show and hide

Comment: Look at the :visible selector, you have just to test if your element is visible => $("#P1").is(":visible")

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine !! for me, You can use below code.

- JavaScript

`

```
<script src="js8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#P1").hide();
        $("#P2").hide();
        $("#P3").hide();
        $("#P4").hide();
        $('input[id^=B]').click(function () {
            var index = $(this).attr('id').replace('B', '');
            if ($(this).val() == "Show") {
                $('#P' + index).show();
                $(this).val("Hide")
            }
            else {
                $('#P' + index).hide();
                $(this).val("Show")
            }


        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: #user3202862 - If answer is useful, Please click on 'correct' and give 'upvote' so it will helps other to find out correct solution.